# Figma plugin access installed components

Tags: typescript, figma, figma-api

Is there a way to tap into installed components (not just components used in the document)?

For instance, if I have an alert component, and I want my plugin to generate an alert component in the document, how would I retrieve a component listed in the assets tab but not yet used in the document?

Comment: Please make your question clear with example

Comment: @PrabeshGouli Ok, I have a component named `Alert` in a group called `Web Library`. In my plugin, I'd like that Alert to be inserted in the document with overrides. How do I do that? Use `ComponentNode`? I'm looking for an example.